# How to put files from a staged folder into a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I uploaded a zipped folder which contained about 200 sub folders and about 3000 XML files per sub folder to an internal stage in snowflake.

Im having trouble putting the XML files into a table I created. I am running the command below to try to and upload the files, but it returns with no files uploaded. Any ideas? I guess my question is is how do I tell snow sql to access the XML files in my folder and sub folders to put them into my table.

copy into trial_data_xml from @clinical file_format='xml_load' pattern='.*/.*/.*[.]xml[.]gz';

Answer (score 1):

If you only have XML files in your stage, the following command will copy all of them:

```
copy into trial_data_xml 
from @clinical 
file_format = (format_name = 'xml_load');
```

More information: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-local-file-system-copy.html

Comment: The XML files are in a zipped folder (.zip) in my stage. So, the XML files are in the stage, but they are in a folder that I uploaded to the stage.

Comment: Files should be compressed separately, not as a collection of files.